Ethernet Transformer - What is the difference between these two versions?
I am trying to select a transformer to convert to base-T Ethernet and found these two variants on a datasheet:

Every other parameter is the same between the two variants, so what does the dotted line connecting the windings in the F30 type mean? I haven't seen it before. The part in question is the ALANS100X1-2F30DT.

I would guess it means that the transformers are wound around a common core.

Manufacturer's product page here: https://abracon.com/parametric/lantransformers/ALANS100X1-2F30DT unfortunately, they don't really say anything. Perhaps you can contact their technical support for more information.

The dashed line is not actually connecting the windings. It may be hard to see with this schematic layout, but actually it's connecting the cores of the two common-mode chokes. This is a standard schematic symbol that indicates that what is drawn as two magnetic cores is in fact one magnetic core.
What it means in this case is that instead of having two two-wire common-mode chokes, the second model has one four-wire common-mode choke. This is more effective at filtering some types of noise and worse at filtering others, and whether it would even make any significant difference at all depends on your application. For well-behaved applications that have short shielded cable runs far from sources of interference, it wouldn't really matter at all; but for very long unshielded cable runs that share a conduit with several other signal lines, mains power, and a VFD cable, it may make the difference between working and not working. (Actually, I'd be surprised if any amount of filtering would get it working in that situation, but you get the idea.)
